# Am I required to be current in my aircraft type to start CFI training?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, cfi

Do i have to be current on my type (Cessna 172) to start flying the flight instructor training course?

Comment: Cessna 172 is not a type

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking about part 61 or part 141 training? If it's part 141, your school might have some currency requirements but you would need to ask them directly.

Comment: I am not meaning to be rude. I think there is a glaringly obvious issue with this question. If you want to get your CFI, you should be well versed in Title 14 CFR, especially parts 61 & 91. Or, you should at least be willing to research it. Your students will expect and deserve nothing less from you. If you are not planning to get your CFI. And, you are just asking out of curiosity, see my answer, below.

Comment: My thoughts also, word for word @DeanF.

Comment: The FAA does not require any type of currency to fly a non-turbine, single-pilot certified, light GA aircraft under 12500 pounds and fewer than 9 pax seat (excluding the pilot’s seat). There is a currency requirement to fly any aircraft IFR. And, there is a currency requirement to fly passengers. There is a currency requirement of 24 months for on your pilot certificate (license), though. This requires an official flight review with a CFI, DPE, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are *not required* to have *any* flight time or aircraft currency for CFI. You *only* need to have a current commercial or ATP certificate, and an endorsement for spin training. Your certificate Class and Category must match the aircraft in which you want to instruct. Type is *not* mentioned in the CFI part of the regs. You will need a type rating to be PIC in any aircraft requiring a type rating. A Cessna 172 does not require a type rating. See below.

The spin training may require additional hours beyond what is necessary for your commercial or ATP certificate. But, spin training can also be accomplished *during* your previous hours of training for any of your current certificates.

> **61.183 Eligibility requirements.**
>
> To be eligible for a flight instructor certificate or rating a person
>   must:
>
> (a) Be at least 18 years of age;
>
> (b) Be able to read, speak, write, and understand the English
>   language. If the applicant is unable to meet one of these requirements
>   due to medical reasons, then the Administrator may place such
>   operating limitations on that applicant’s flight instructor
>   certificate as are necessary;
>
> (c) Hold either a commercial pilot certificate or airline transport
>   pilot certificate with:
>
> (1) An aircraft category and class rating that is appropriate to the
>   flight instructor rating sought; and
>
> (2) An instrument rating or privileges on that person’s pilot
>   certificate that are appropriate to the flight instructor rating
>   sought, if applying for—
>
> (d) Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor on the
>   fundamentals of instructing listed in §61.185 of this part appropriate
>   to the required knowledge test;
>
> (e) Pass a knowledge test on the areas listed in §61.185(a)
>
> (f) Pass a knowledge test on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed
>   in §61.185(a)(2) and (a)(3) of this part that are appropriate to the
>   flight instructor rating sought;
>
> (g) Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor on the
>   areas of operation listed in §61.187(b) of this part, appropriate to
>   the flight instructor rating sought;
>
> (h) Pass the required practical test that is appropriate to the flight
>   instructor rating sought in an:
>
> (1) Aircraft that is representative of the category and class of
>   aircraft for the aircraft rating sought; or
>
> (2) Flight simulator or approved flight training device that is
>   representative of the category and class of aircraft for the rating
>   sought, and used in accordance with a course at a training center
>   certificated under part 142 of this chapter.
>
> (i) Accomplish the following for a flight instructor certificate with
>   an airplane or a glider rating:
>
> (1) Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor
>   indicating that the applicant is competent and possesses instructional
>   proficiency in stall awareness, spin entry, spins, and spin recovery
>   procedures after providing the applicant with flight training in those
>   training areas in an airplane or glider, as appropriate, that is
>   certificated for spins; and
>
> (2) Demonstrate instructional proficiency in stall awareness, spin
>   entry, spins, and spin recovery procedures. However, upon presentation
>   of the endorsement specified in paragraph (i)(1) of this section an
>   examiner may accept that endorsement as satisfactory evidence of
>   instructional proficiency in stall awareness, spin entry, spins, and
>   spin recovery procedures for the practical test, provided that the
>   practical test is not a retest as a result of the applicant failing
>   the previous test for deficiencies in the knowledge or skill of stall
>   awareness, spin entry, spins, or spin recovery instructional
>   procedures. If the retest is a result of deficiencies in the ability
>   of an applicant to demonstrate knowledge or skill of stall awareness,
>   spin entry, spins, or spin recovery instructional procedures, the
>   examiner must test the person on stall awareness, spin entry, spins,
>   and spin recovery instructional procedures in an airplane or glider,
>   as appropriate, that is certificated for spins;
>
> (j) Log at least 15 hours as pilot in command in the category and
>   class of aircraft that is appropriate to the flight instructor rating
>   sought; and
>
> (k) Comply with the appropriate sections of this part that apply to
>   the flight instructor rating sought.
>
> **61.31 Type rating requirements, additional training, and authorization requirements.**
>
> (a) Type ratings required. A person who acts as a pilot in command of
>   any of the following aircraft must hold a type rating for that
>   aircraft:
>
> (1) Large aircraft (except lighter-than-air).
>
> (2) Turbojet-powered airplanes.
>
> (3) Other aircraft specified by the Administrator through aircraft
>   type certificate procedures.

Comment: I think we can pare that answer down just a little bit to what is specifically related to a Cessna 172 and its use in obtaining a flight instructor certificate.

Comment: @Carlo Felicione - How’s that?

Comment: In other words the question was more narrowly focused on the use of a Cessna 172 for taking the practical test to become a flight instructor, as opposed to every single requirement for application to become a flight instructor

Comment: @CarloFelicione - The question asks nothing about the Checkride (practical exam). It does not even ask if you can fly the C172 during training. It asks if he has to be current on type to START the training COURSE. The question makes it sound like the OP thinks the CFI course has a flight component. Although you do need to know how to fly to commercial standards from the right seat, the CFI training is more about being able to teach and less about flying. There are many CFI courses that are ground only.

Comment: As far as the Checkride, there is no currency requirement when flying with a duly rated instructor or DPE. If the DPE is not acting as PIC, you will need an endorsement from an instructor to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type rating for a Cessna 172.  The only requirements by law (see [14 CFR §61.183](https://www.govregs.com/regulations/expand/title14_chapterI_part61_subpartH_section61.183)) to use one to apply for a flight instructor certificate are that a person must hold at least:

- A Commercial Pilot Certificate with an Airplane Single Engine Land category and class rating
- An Instrument Airplane rating
- Hold at least a valid Third Class Medical Certificate, or meet the requirements of §61.113 (i).

Day/night currency to carry passengers per 14 CFR §61.57 will not be required to undergo flight instructor training in the C172.

Comment: Could you please add info about the source for this, just to make the answer more credible as this is a case of rules and regulations.

Comment: You don‘t need a Third Class Medical any more—Basic Med will be fine.

Comment: For the training, yes.  But you will need an active medical if you intend to take the check ride.  It’s best to get that out of the way prior to spending big bucks on flight training.

Comment: @CarloFelicione In the US, you do not need a Third Class medical to take any  checkride—basic med will suffice. You can use basic med to instruct as well. I do agree that if you want to be a professional pilot, you should get a First  Class medical before you start your training if you want to fly for the airlines or Part 135. You’ll need a Second Class medical if you want to fly other commercial operations.

Comment: In my previous comment, I said that you only need basic med for any checkride, but what I meant to say is that you only need basic med for any checkride where you are taking the ride in an airplane that is covered by basic med. So you would need a Third Class medical for a mult-engine checkride or for a Type Rating ride, etc.

Comment: You can conduct PIC duties in a twin using BasicMed.   No regulation against it.  All you’re limited on is the aircraft must be less that 6000lbs, carry no more than 5 passengers, and remain below 18,000 ft and 250 knots.